# Why does foldLeft failed to infer the type?

Tags: scala

Why does it give such an error?

```
scala> 'a' - 'b'
res0: Int = -1

scala> ('a' /: "abc") {_ - _ }
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Char
              ('a' /: "abc") {_ - _ }
                                ^
```

Comment: The types don't match - your accumulator starts as a `Char` but your accumulator function returns an `Int` when it should be a `Char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lee says in the comments, the types don't match - here are some solutions.

We can either start the fold with an `Int`, or the output of the fold function can be converted to a `Char`:

```
scala> (0 /: "abc")(_ - _)
res1: Int = -294

scala> ('a'.toInt /: "abc")(_ - _)
res2: Int = -197

scala> ('a' /: "abc")((a,b)=> (a-b).toChar)
res3: Char = ?
```